# Wrong power supply for monitor

Tags: display

A few days ago I got a monitor for free without a power supply.

It said DC 12v was needed for a power supply but I used a different one (about the size of a cellphone charger) to test if the monitor worked, and it did.

Today I used the same power source and powered the monitor on for a good 2-3 minutes then I heard a pretty loud *pop.* The monitor immediately shut off.

Now I try using the same power source to see if the monitor still works, and it does, it powers on, but as soon as the screen turns on it immediately shuts back off.

Did I blow out the battery? Will the monitor still work?

The power supply I used had an output of 24 volts if that helps. Nothing seems to have changed from when I first tested it out, except the fact that the monitor now shuts back down as soon as I press the power button.

Comment: Monitors don't have batteries.

Comment: Yes;  you have damaged the monitor;  No;  you have not blown out its batteries, it has none, but it is damaged

Comment: It sounds like you blew up a capacitor inside the monitor. What was the voltage output of the power supply you were using?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: You could have got away with a PSU with a higher ampage than specified… but not a higher voltage. You killed it. Time to buy a new monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the pop didn't come from the power supply? If the voltage was correct then it shouldn't have blown anything in the monitor. I would expect a monitor to use a good deal more power than a cell phone charger can provide, so if something failed, then power supply is what I'd be checking first.

It may sound kind of primitive, but in this case, I'd be resorting to the sniff test. Burned out electronics have a very distinctive smell. It's usually quite obvious which component has blown.

Comment: Cell phone chargers get shorted all the time. It's rare to find one that can't tolerate that.

Comment: Why would cell phone chargers short all the time, and how exactly would they tolerate it? A short will draw basically unlimited power until something burns out, or shuts off.

Comment: The short all the time because people fumble as they connect the micro USB connectors. They tolerate it by having circuits that limit how quickly the current can increase and how high the current can go. It can be as simple as a resistor on the input side of a voltage regulator.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If the power supply didn't fail, then the only other option is that the voltage was too high, or the monitor was faulty.

Comment: It could just have been the monitor's time to go. The monitor may never have been working correctly and that's why he got it for free. The power supply could have failed due to overload. The power supply might be unable to supply what the monitor needs. We don't really know for sure, but the pop sound is definitely not a good thing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz A device simply drawing slightly too much current perhaps wouldn't trigger this fail-safe, as it wouldn't behave exactly like a short. Also there's no way to know whether the charger was a reputable brand, or some cheap imitation junk.

Comment: The voltage was not correct (12V vs 24V).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Then you almost certainly blew up one or more capacitors in the monitor.

Comment: Yes, the monitor is almost certainly ruined now. 12V and 24V are not interchangeable. Even if it could be fixed, it wouldn't be cost effective.